# Should I use Undefined or Null as default for a property that is about to receive its value from a GET response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Lets say I want to render the product information, however, the a GET request must go through first so I can assign the response to the product. My question is, in the `data()`, should the default value for product be undefined or null, and is there any difference?

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ product }}
    <div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios"

export default {
    data(){
        return{
            product: undefined,
            productId: this.$route.params.productId
        }
    },
    methods:{
        async getProduct(){
            let response = await axios.get("/product/" + this.productId)
            this.product = response.data.product
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getProduct()
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it really matter? You will need to check it anyways, before accessing it. Because `this.product.someproperty` with throw an error, for both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no answer to the "should be" part of the question since it is a matter of opinion, but it may be of benefit to contrast the differences between and the commonality of the two.

### `undefined`

Undefined is a data type in JavaScript with a single value, `undefined` and is

- Returned from a function by default if no other return value is specified,
- When reading a variable that has never been initialized,
- When reading a property of an object that has never been set (including array entries whose subscript is a property of the Array object), and
- When a accessing a variable, property or function return value that has been explicitly set to `undefined` - possible because it is a data type after all.

Undefined values are treated as `false` in a comparison statement or ternary `?` expression, excluding strict equality comparisons of the `null === false` kind.

The undefined data type is not supported in JSON: `undefined` is converted to `null` when serializing a data object into JSON text.

### `null`

Null is also a JavaScript data type with a single value `null`. In many ways it is similar to `undefined` with important differences:

- `null` values never arise by default and must always be explicitly assigned to a variable, property or returned from a function.
- `null` is a supported value when serializing data objects into JSON.
- `null` has a historic meaning of "no object" or an empty object class similar to the empty set phi in mathematics.

---

Regarding you choice of usage, initializing `product` to `undefined` highlights that the value has not been obtained as yet, but also risks being interpreted as a bug in a function that returns `undefined` when asked to return `product`. Returning `null` resolves any "this is not a mistake" questions and is well established practice.